# How to define single icon for main window and exe file?

Tags: c#, wpf

Usually I have to set 2 different icons. One in the project's settings tab, and one to the `Icon` property of main window. Is there a way to define single icon for the whole application (all windows and exe)?

**Update:** to be more concrete. I have app that is 100kb in size. I want to embed icon that is 300kb in size and want my app to be 400kb instead of 700

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to set the icon in your project's properties:

[image]

For taskbar you need to change your main window's Icon:
[image]

Comment: Main window and taskbar icons will still be default windows .exe icons

Comment: For that you need to specify the icon in your main form. See my response now.

Comment: I know that. The question is how to define icon in SINGLE place so that all windows will have that icon.

Comment: @Poma Sorry now I understand what you mean. You need to specify the same icon in two places.

Comment: Whan I add icon to project exe file becomes 400 kb (even when it's build action set to 'none'). After I select it it project settings exe immediately becomes 700kb

Comment: Ok, so your concern is the size of resulting exe? You can keep your icon separately and load it dynamically when the app is started. Sepcifying an icon in project settings the effect will be that that icon will be displayed for you app when you ALT-TAB through currently running apps.

Comment: Looks like I found how to do it. I have to add icon to Resorces and set 'linked at compile time'. Then when I set icon in project properties it becomes 400kb AND all window's default icon is set correctly. Don't know why it's different when I simply add it to project. So it's just works :)

Comment: by the way, how to load icon dynamically from exe at runtime?

Comment: Thanks, this answer was very useful for me. I gave you my vote!!

Answer (score 17):

When you set your exe icon, WPF will use that for all Windows you create. **However, it doesn't do it in debug mode** - that's because the "entry point" for your process is the .vshost.exe, not your exe. But if you use Ctrl+F5 (run without debugging), you should find all Windows get the exe icon. You shouldn't have to set it on each Window.

To make it work properly in debug mode, I generally set up a Style which I apply to each window, which sets the application icon.